# JQuery Dragging stops working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a UI Dialog box that drags. But it only drags once. After that I get the drag curser, but it doesnt drag any more.What can be causing this?
Thanks

Comment: Gremlins?  Your source code would help a ton.

Answer (score 0):

If any javascript error occurs on the drop event, this could cause following javascript to stop functioning as expected.